# MYSQL - field type for a file name?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

getting to know my databases, at some point in my application the user would be able to upload a photo (or photos). My friend told me that using filenames would be better as opposed to a blob of text. Should I use varchar or varbinary for this?

Also if the user would upload more pictures (lets say max would be 10) would it be better to create a table for the pictures and a connecting one such as userspictures or would it be better to store all the pictures in a string that would be separated by commas or something to that effect?

Help is really appreciated thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your friend said, it's better to store only the filename in the database.
I would suggest `VARCHAR(255)`.

I really recommend you to create another table for multiple files:

```sql
CREATE TABLE photos (
  id INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED,
  filename VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

SELECT id, filename FROM photos WHERE user_id = [user_id]
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the quick answer! BTW I also added the UNSIGNED and AUTO_INCREMENT in my primary keys.

Answer (score 1):

Storing all the pictures in a comma separated string would be a violation of the 1st Normal Form, which can lead to inefficient queries. You have to reduce the data to atomic form, so in such cases, always form a separate table to store individual data items.

Comment: Yup, thanks for the answer. Guess I need to reread normalization.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the image filename in database with `varchar` datatype instead  of `blob` because `blob` (Binary Large Object) datatypes are used to store large amounts of binary data. Save the images on the server and pass the image name to the database. You create another table for multiple files, it's fine.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your quick reply :)

Comment: @cupidvogel:i want to say one word to you.